# Validar el ingreso de datos

Tags: java

Me podrían ayudar con la implementación de un código en java para la validación de datos, por ejemplo, al pasar por teclado un `String "1234"`, o bien `"12.34"`, o bien `"12.34\n"` o bien `"\n"`, o bien que no exceda el numero de dígitos requeridos (no se si se entiende las formas de ingreso).

Es decir que el dato ingresado vaya pasando por distintas restricciones y obliguen al usuario a ingresar lo que pide el programa, y en el caso de ser el `"\n"` se lo convierta al carácter `"\0"`.

Creo que esto los programadores lo llaman "error trapping" o código basura... Espero que se haya entendido a lo que me refiero ya que buscando este tema en la red no está del todo claro, y me ayudaría a que mis códigos fueran un poco mejor.

```
/* Código de Java: Validación de dato */
public class ValidarAcceso {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        final int MIN = -1000;
        final int MAX = +1000;

        int inicio;
        int termina;
        double respuesta;

        System.out.println("Este programa calcula la suma de los cuadrados de enteros.\n"+
                           "en un rango entre -1000 y +1000.\n"+
                           "Ingresa los límites (0 en los dos límites para terminar)\n"+
                           "Límite bajo: " );
        inicio = obten_int();
        System.out.println("Limite alto: ");
        termina = obten_int();

        while( inicio != 0 || termina != 0)
        {
            if( mal_limites( inicio, termina, MIN, MAX ) )
                System.out.println( "Otra vez por favor\n" );
            else
            {
                respuesta = suma_cuadrados( inicio, termina );
                System.out.println("La suma de los cuadrados de los enteros ");
                System.out.printf("entre %d y %d es %g\n", inicio, termina, respuesta );
            }
            System.out.println("Entra los límites (0 en los dos "+
                               " para terminar)\n");
            System.out.println( "limite bajo: " );
            inicio = obten_int();
            System.out.println( "limite alto: " );
            termina = obten_int();
        }
        System.out.println( "Listo.\n" );
    }

    public static int obten_int()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ingreso;

        while( ( ingreso = scan.nextInt() ) != 1 )
        {
            String cadena = new String( scan.nextLine() );
            while( ( scan.nextLine() ) !="\n" )
                cadena.charAt(ingreso);
            System.out.println(" no es entero.\nFavor entrar un ");
            System.out.println( "entero como 25, -178, o 3: ");
        }
        return ingreso;
    }

    public static double suma_cuadrados( int a, int b )
    {
        double total = 0;
        int i;

        for( i = a; i <= b; i++ )
            total +=i * i;

        return total;
    }

    public static boolean mal_limites( int inicio, int termina, int bajo, int alto )
    {
        boolean no_bueno = false;

        if( inicio > termina )
        {
            System.out.printf("%d no es menor que %d.\n", inicio, termina );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        if( inicio < bajo || termina < bajo )
        {
            System.out.printf("Valores deber ser >= %d.\n", bajo );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        if( inicio > alto || termina > alto )
        {
            System.out.printf("Valores deber ser <= %d.\n", alto );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        return no_bueno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido. Te recomiendo que mires el tema de [tag:regex] que sirven para validar textos (caracteres, longitud y sustituciones). Cuando tengas una implementacion, aqui puedes preguntar las dudas al respecto con ejemplos o errores obtenidos. Un saludo

Comment: Te recomiendo que muestres y explayes tu postura con tu código y a que quieres llegar. La idea no es que te pasemos el código totalmente resuelto, sino que seamos una ayuda para ti

Comment: Ok... bueno aquí tengo un código que estuve intentando traducir al lenguaje Java... el original es de un código hecho en C, hay ciertas sentencias que no las he podido traducir a Java, no conozco mucho del lenguaje, y al momento de intentar correr el programa, no funciona correctamente debido a esto. En el siguiente comentario les paso el código, ya que creo que no se alcance a copiar en este complemente.

Comment: Perdón si es un poco desprolijo mis comentarios, no se bien por el momento como hay que moverse en esta pagina.

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu código funcione debes reforzar la función `obten_int()` de la siguiente manera:

```
public static int obten_int()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                return scan.nextInt();
            } else {
                scan.next();
                System.out.println(" no es entero.\nFavor entrar un ");
                System.out.println( "entero como 25, -178, o 3: ");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Recibido EOF (forzamos 0)");
            return 0;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Con este cambio tu aplicación funciona correctamente.

Si modificamos el bucle de introducción de datos para hacerlo más claro, el resultado final en `ValidarAcceso.java` sería:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/* Código de Java: Validación de dato */
public class ValidarAcceso {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        final int MIN = -1000;
        final int MAX = +1000;

        int inicio;
        int termina;
        double respuesta;

        System.out.println("\nEste programa calcula la suma de los cuadrados de enteros " +
                           "en un rango entre " + MIN + " y " + MAX + ".\n" +
                           "Intruduzca los valores inferior y superior (0 en ambos para terminar)\n\n");

        while (true) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.print( "\nIntroduzca el valor inferior: " );
                inicio = obten_int();
                System.out.print( "\nIntroduzca el valor superior: " );
                termina = obten_int();
                if( mal_limites( inicio, termina, MIN, MAX ) == false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( inicio == 0 && termina == 0) break;
            respuesta = suma_cuadrados( inicio, termina );
            System.out.println("\nLa suma de los cuadrados de los enteros ");
            System.out.printf("entre %d y %d es %g\n", inicio, termina, respuesta );
        }
        System.out.println( "\nListo.\n" );
    }

    public static int obten_int()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ingreso;

        do {
            if (scan.hasNext()) {
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    return scan.nextInt();
                } else {
                    scan.next();
                    System.out.print("No ha introducido un número correcto.\n\nFavor entrar un entero como 25, -178, o 3: ");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Recibido EOF (forzamos 0)");
        return 0;
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public static double suma_cuadrados( int a, int b )
    {
        double total = 0;
        int i;

        for( i = a; i <= b; i++ )
            total +=i * i;

        return total;
    }

    public static boolean mal_limites( int inicio, int termina, int bajo, int alto )
    {
        boolean no_bueno = false;

        if( inicio > termina )
        {
            System.out.printf("%d no es menor que %d.\n", inicio, termina );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        if( inicio < bajo || termina < bajo )
        {
            System.out.printf("Valores deber ser >= %d.\n", bajo );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        if( inicio > alto || termina > alto )
        {
            System.out.printf("Valores deber ser <= %d.\n", alto );
            no_bueno = true;
        }

        return no_bueno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ayuda OscarGarcia. :)

Comment: @pablosabadini en el caso de que la respuesta sea lo que buscabas, recomiendo que la marques como respuesta correcta.

Comment: De nada. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para que quede constancia que tu pregunta ya está resuelta. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crearte una clase para todos los tipos de datos `int`, `long`, `double`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, `String` y hacer lo mismo y así siempre estarán validados los datos introducidos.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class pruebas
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
            
        System.out.println("introdce un numero");
        int num = leerInt(); //leeInt(); 
        System.out.println("numero "+num);
        
    }
    
    
    //Método1 -leerInt()    
    public static int leerInt(){
        
        Integer y= 0;
        do{
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            String x = teclado.next();
            try {
                y = Integer.parseInt(x);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.out.println("debes introducir un 
                                numero entero");         
            }
            
        }while(y instanceof Integer);
        return y;
    }
                    

    
    //METODO 2 - leeInt();
    public static int leeInt() {

        BufferedReader teclado=new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReaderr(System.in));

        Integer x = 0;/*instancia de Integer a la que asignamos 
                     el valor 0 para inicializarla.*/
        do{
            try {           
                x = Integer.valueOf(teclado.readLine());
                /*si consigue asignar a x el valor leido por 
                  teclado entonces con break paramos el    
                  do-while y devolvemos x, sino 
                  continuamos al catch.*/  
                                                            
                 break;
                
            }catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
                /*sino lo consigue entra aqui y mostramos el 
                  mensaje.*/
                System.out.println("debes introducir un 
                                numero entero");
            }
            /*como x desde el principio vale 0 es por tanto una 
              instancia de Integer, entonces repetimos el bucle, 
              así, hasta que Integer.valueOf() consiga asignar
              un valor nuevo a x diferente al inicial que era 0, 
              entonces con break se saldra del bucle*/

        }while(x instanceof Integer);
        
      
        return x;
}
```

Comment: podrías explicar tu código?, se que los comentarios describe lo que hace cada cosa, pero siempre una breve explicación ayuda mucho :D

Comment: estoy en ello, es la primera publicación que hago aquí y es casi más complicado que programar

Comment: jeje tranqui, iras aprendiendo, además te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), eso te ayudara a realizar mejores respuestas y así obtendrás más reputación!

Comment: ok no te preocupes y muchas gracias por colaborar!

Comment: ahora lo he visto ahí arriba a quedado mejor la verdad, gracias a ti!